# How to pass a nested object as an argument to mutation using GraphQL?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, graphql-js

So, I am writing a node.js app that acts as GraphQL server. I have a schema like that:

```
type Program {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  cover: String!
  groups: [Group]
}

type Group {
  name: String!
  exercises: [Exercise]
}

type Exercise {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
  tags: [String]
  cover: String!
  images: [String]
  text: String!
}
```

And I need to create a `Program` that includes some `group`s (`group` is stored inside a `Program` in one document, that's why).

How can I pass a nested object as an argument to mutation so it will create a nested object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called GraphQLInputObjectType,
which is just like GraphQLObjectType, but works for input (arguments)

http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/#graphqlinputobjecttype

Enjoy :)